# Is there a workaround for the 90 day limit in the EU?

Tags: eu, canadian-citizens, 90-180-visa-rules

Would this be possible? As a Canadian

1. I fly into the EU, e.g., Germany
2. Travel around the EU for 120 days.
3. Then travel OVERLAND to a non-EU country and fly home from there?

Will they check my passport when leaving the EU by rail/bus?

Comment: How is this a workaround? There are a few ways to evade Schengen exit checks (this isn't one of them usually), but the burden is still on you to comply with the law, and if you're caught, you could be fined and face a ban.

Comment: Why do you even want to work around the rule? If you really do want to spend 120 days in the EU and have the means to do so, then just apply for a corresponding visa.

Comment: You seem to be asking for a way to break the law and get away with it. If so, the only answer you'll get here is "don't". If not so, please edit to clarify this.

Comment: There is no "90 day limit in the EU", by the way. There's a 90-days-of-every-180 limit for **the Schengen area**, which comprises some (but not all!) EU member countries as well as a few countries that are not EU members.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be asking for advice on how to break the law and get away with it.

Comment: Go to Iceland and then see if you can get on board a cargo ship to Canada.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in principle documents are checked at land borders, sometimes even more thoroughly. There are many details in the Schengen Borders Code on how these checks are to be conducted, what type of lanes, what type of signs, etc. Same thing for ships entering and leaving the Schengen area, all this has been considered carefully. In practice, the borders between Hungary or Poland and the Ukraine or Serbia are certainly policed very intensively as are the Greek borders.

Technically, places like Andorra aren't in the Schengen area and border checks are very lax so that's a land border you may be able to cross. But there is also no airport so that wouldn't help you at all. Before Switzerland joined, the checks there were also hit-and-miss, although in my experience trains and busses were checked more, not less, extensively than, say, cars. I have heard more stories of people getting away with minor overstays or missing stamps at airports in France or Italy than at land borders.

Furthermore, the Schengen Borders Code explicitly puts the burden of proof on you, the visitor. *You* should actively seek an exit stamp where appropriate or, if you don't have one, prove by other means that you really weren't present in the Schengen area longer than you were supposed to. If border guards feel like punishing you to the full extent of the law, a missing exit stamp is all they need. They don't need to catch you in the act and can still impose a fine or a ban later on (e.g. if you present the same passport on a subsequent visit).

In practice, I am not sure how common it really is. For all I know, for a minor to medium overstay and if you are already on the exit, you might get away with a slap on the wrist or a modest fine but the law really gives border guards a lot of latitude, with a standard of proof well below that of criminal law so you cannot count on this to avoid problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a workaround. Your passport will be checked by Schengen authorities on exit even if traveling by rail or bus. If they see that you have overstayed the will likely issue you a fine and or a ban.

Answer (score 1):

If you manage to sneak out of the Schengen area by land/sea with out being caught, then you obviously won't be fined. However, when you next apply for a visa (or even a transit visa, if you need one), then you'll have some very pointed questions to answer.

Comment: As a Canadian, the OP does not need either of those. But s/he might still get questions or even a fine when reentering the Schengen area.